# Open Access form with pointer on record

Tags: vba, ms-access, highlight, subform

I have a form with a tabular subform and want to set the record pointer to be on a particular record (on or near current date) and this record highlighted.
Following code is used to set the pointer after the desired record is found:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSelectRecord
```

Unfortunately, this works **only when the form/subform is already open**: then the record marker is highlighted as desired.
HOWEVER, when the same code is run from Form_current() upon opening the form, the code line runs (I checked this !) but has no effect at all: when the form displays, THE HIGHLIGHT IS ON THE FIRST FIELD (in the subform) !

Similarly, the attempt to deselect the field contents works only after the form is already open, but not upon opening the form :

```
    With Forms![MyForm]![MySubform]![MyHighlightedField]
        On Error Resume Next
        .SelStart = 0
        .SelLength = 0
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
```

Is there any way to enforce the desired record marker to be highlighted on opening the form/subform ?

Comment: PS: Same code works correctly with simple form, but not with subform - even when in Form_current() of subform.

Comment: I am sorry, I am confused. Try to upload images of it.

Comment: I think will have to first set focus to subform container control.